# Boost.preprocessor : BOOST_PP_EQUAL not working

Tags: c++, c, boost, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

Hello I have a problem with Boost.Preprocessor in C.  I believe C++ and C macro behaves exactly the same so using Boost.Preprocessor is fine in C and anyway I intend to do a small fully preprocessor library. My issui is that I cannot compile a tiny program using `BOOST_PP_EQUAL`.  Here is the sample code you can build:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define TUPLE (0,1,2)
#define IS_NON_ZERO(NODE) BOOST_PP_EQUAL(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE(NODE),0)

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    x = IS_NON_ZERO(TUPLE);
    printf("result: %d\n",x);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm using clang and gcc and both told me that the macro BOOST_PP_NOT_EQUALS does not exist!

```
tiny.c:6:27: error: ‘BOOST_PP_NOT_EQUAL_0’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

What is wrong with my code ?  Thanks in advance !

EDIT: Here is the non-macro line using the `-E` flag.

```
 x = BOOST_PP_COMPL_BOOST_PP_NOT_EQUAL_CHECK_BOOST_PP_NOT_EQUAL_BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE((0,1,2))(0, BOOST_PP_NOT_EQUAL_0);
```

What the heck ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `-DBOOST_PP_VARIADICS=1` to your compiler.

Comment: +1. Or simply add `#define BOOST_PP_VARIADICS` before the headers.

Comment: I actually switched to standard that defines `BOOST_PP_VARIADICS`.